# How do I cast a generic value at runtime in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, struct

I have a generic struct which is like

```
public struct Range<T>
```

and has two properties, `From` and `To` of type `T`.

The struct also has a member like:

```
public bool FromGreaterTo
{
    get { return (bool)Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(From, To) > 0 };
}
```

I create a `ValidationAttribute` for properties of this struct.

In the override of the `IsValid` method I do know that it is of Type `Range<>` and `T is int?` or whatever.

How can I dynamically cast the `value` parameter (which is actually the `Range<>` property) so I can access the `FromGreaterTo` member?

I already tried something like

```
private Range<T> Cast<T> (object valueToCast, T genericType)
{
    return (Range<T>)valueToCast;
}
```

which throws an exception, that this cast is invalid.

Any ideas or workarounds on that?

Comment: why do you have a parameter "genericType" in the method Cast<T> if you're not using it?

Comment: Also, who is "value" and where does it come from?

Comment: @ArthurRizzo: This is just to call the method like `var casted = Cast(...)` instead of invoking the method with `GetType().GetMethod().MakeGeneric().Invoke()...` @helb casting to object before is not worlking

Comment: If you know `T` and you know `valueToCast` is a `Range<T>` then the cast should succeed. It will only fail if `valueToCast` is not a `Range<T>` for some `T` or `T` does not match what you think it is.

Comment: @Lee: I know T by `value.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]` which seems not to work

Comment: @KingKerosin - If you don't' know `T` statically then why are you trying to cast it?

Comment: @Lee: In order to have access to `FromGreaterTo`

Comment: @KingKerosin - You can't cast if you don't know the target type statically. If you don't want to introduce a new type as @oblivioussage suggests then you can use reflection or dynamic to access the `FromGreaterTo` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Make Range a class and give it an abstract base class.**

```
public abstract class Range
{
    public abstract bool FromGreaterTo { get; }
}

public class Range<T> : Range
{
    // existing Range<T> code
}
```

Then you can just cast your `Range<T>` object to a `Range` object and call its `FromGreaterTo` property.